# Python: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input().lower().split()
a.sort()
count = 1
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
        count += 1   
    if a[i] != a[i+1]:
        b[a[i]] = []
        b[a[i]].append(count)
        count = 1
```

"Программа должна считывать одну строку со стандартного ввода и выводить для каждого уникального слова в этой строке число его повторений (без учёта регистра) "

В данном случае у меня не получается полностью перебрать весь список, если я делаю range(len(a)-1), то у меня итератор упускает последнюю ячейку.

Comment: Не проще использовать `collections.Counter` ?

Comment: Ваше решение в принципе неправильно, даже если вы победите проблему с последней ячейкой. Вы сравниваете только соседние слова. Но ведь слово может повторятся не обязательно подряд, копии слова могут встретиться вообще в разных частях строки.

Comment: Именно по этому список сортируется и имеется счетчик повторений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так будет попроще:

```
a = input().lower().split()
a.sort()
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    count = a.count(a[i])
    print(a[i], count)
    i += count
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно проще через модуль [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter

word_list = input().lower().split()
print(word_list)

for name, number in Counter(word_list).items():
    print(name, number)
```